# Finding distances associated with change in latitude and longitude at given location

Tags: coordinate-system, data, distance, latitude-longitude, united-states

I am writing a program that uses GPS lat and long coordinates and a time change to determine speed with the output in units of m/s (precise to 0.1 m if feasible, but 1 m is sufficient).  When researching the distances associated with a change in latitude and longitude, however, I saw just how variable it was.  When continuing my research to find the distances associated with the general location I'm interested in, I could not find such a resource.

I know what area this program will be used in (Boston, Massachusetts) and the distance travelled during each time step is short enough that I can assume it moved across a plane.  As such, I am not looking for a formula to use in the general case over long distances but a look-up table or data base that has the relevant distances I need.

Where should I look online (or elsewhere) for this information?

Comment: Geodesic distance https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/cgi-bin/GeodSolve looks promising. You will need to indicate what API you're using to write your program to get more specific help, a codeblock would also be nice. Note that sub metre GPS readings need *sub metre GPS units*, you're not going to get that order of accuracy with a cell phone.

Comment: It's a complex topic but the duplicate came up in this search: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcoordinate-system%5D+%5Breferences%5D+distance  For more references consider reviewing https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coordinate-system%2breferences?tab=Votes.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thank you for your help but the question you linked doesn't help me due to the small scale I'm working on.  I have edited my question to differentiate it from the other and to specify what I am looking for.  Is there a way to re-open my question?

Comment: If it's open data (lookup table, database) that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.